# Smart group interaction with "display results as" options in advanced search

Tags: smartgroups, search-results, display

I would like to create a smart group of Members by membership status and display that as 'Memberships' via the "Display results as.." field in the Advanced search. I want the Memberships display because it offers easy access to the 'Renew' option for repetitive off-line renewals as well as offering different options for exporting templates.

If I set up the search in Advanced search with "Display results as.." set to Contacts, the results page gives me the option for 'New Smart Group' with no problem. However the same search with the Display results option set to 'Memberships' does not have the option for "New smart group' with the results.

Am I missing something, or is there no way to create a smart group for membership display?
CiviCRM 4.6.24, Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you first create your smart group with the 'contacts' view (groups are by definition groups of contacts)... you can then search on 'group'=your group and 'display as'='memberships'. In my experience that works for smart groups as well.

Comment: Thanks, Eli. That is similar, but perhaps a bit quicker, than what I had been doing which is selecting the group from Manage Groups and then clicking on the two levels of "Edit group..." to get the Advanced search window where I could change the "Display results as..."  to Memberships. I was just hoping that the display method could be saved in the smart group definition to simplify the workflow for less experienced operatives.

Comment: Now that I think about it more... I wonder if this is a bug or a feature. It looks like you CAN do what you're describing with 'display as'='event participants', but not memberships. Next place to check about it might be the issue queue in JIRA but I haven't had time to look. EDIT: I re-read what you said and I don't think event participants will save the display as participants, just the contacts you searched for - since a group can only be defined by contacts rather than another table as far as I know.